# Listing of JSON objects with image as attribute

Tags: angularjs, json, image, uri

So I'm trying to build a table or list of missing persons, the list will repeat an array of JSON objects with ng-repeat.

The problem, broken up:

1.Why is JSON giving me a parse error? It isn't the base64 image code, that part is correct and works fine when included in the index.
2.Is there a better way to include an image in JSON?
3.Is JSON the best answer for this problem? What are my other options?

My JSON file is

JSON

```
{
  "FullName": "Lucy Ann Johnson",
  "WentMissing": "1961",
  "Age:": "20",
  "Description": "Short brunette, was last seen wearing a green dress.",
  "Image": "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,data\">"
}
```

User lin has already corrected my syntax in a previous question, but I still get an error : 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 10333

#### Index

```
<div class="container"
         style="
                margin-top:0px width=100%" ui-view> 
    </div>
```

#### Controllers

```
/*globals angular, console, $http, data, ListingsController*/
var mymodule = angular.module("controllers", []);

mymodule.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {console.log("HomeController"); });


mymodule.controller("AboutController", function ($scope) {console.log("AboutController"); });

mymodule.controller("ListingsController", function ($scope, $http) {var data = $http.get("js/data.json"); });

mymodule.controller("ContactController", function ($scope) {console.log("ContactController"); });

mymodule.controller("ReportController", function ($scope) {console.log("ReportController"); });
```

#### app.js

```
/*global angular*/

angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'controllers'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })


        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        })



        .state('listings', {
            url: '/listings',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Listings.html',
            controller: 'ListingsController'
        })


        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        })


        .state('report', {
            url: '/report',
            templateUrl: 'templates/Report.html',
            controller: 'ReportController'
        });



});
```

Comment: Is the JSON in your question the one which throws the error? `position 10333` seems far behind the image attribute you provided here.

Comment: Looking at the error it seems that it's coming from a parse function within the angular library trying to parse. The answer below suggests parsing is not necessary, but I don't know how to go around it if that's the case.

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions nyx?

Comment: @lin i gave up on that bit of the project :( but thanks for your help!

Comment: Lol ok =) good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As we already have a `JSON object` with valid `JSON` then why you want to parse it.

[image]

- If it is a `JSON String` then if you parse it using `JSON.parse()` it is parsing the `JSON string` successfully without any error.

```js
var jsonStr = '{ "FullName": "Lucy Ann Johnson","WentMissing": "1961","Age:": "20","Description": "Short brunette, was last seen wearing a green dress.","Image": "<img src=\'data:image/jpeg;base64,data\'>" }';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

console.log(jsonObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fixed the JSON syntax error (which is actually not able to reproduce because of lag of information in your question) you could put out a rendered list of by `ng-repeat`-ing the array like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2jpybo7/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [{
      "FullName": "Peter Power",
      "WentMissing": "1941",
      "Age:": "77",
      "Description": "Short brunette, was last seen wearing a green dress.",
      "Image": "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"
    },{
      "FullName": "Lucy Ann Johnson",
      "WentMissing": "1961",
      "Age:": "20",
      "Description": "Short brunette, was last seen wearing a green dress.",
      "Image": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAY8ElEQVR4Xu2dCbxVVb3HucwagzY9QUsInmQEMlxAJAuemAxqWiIaoCYKUpZAgz2rT74+vQYVhzRABIKMNMRARdEEonyIzAThqyeCqFDpR5PhMg/v+ztv7/P2PexhrX32OWefe8/6fM7nnnv22mv9h9/6r/+a/quqQSWVvQT69+/ffM+ePcOPHz9+WVVVVfWxY8dOc5j6W8OGDdfw24IWLVrMXbZs2YFcZqvKnvt6zkDPnj2/iMInoWhX6UES2QlAJq5bt+433gwVAJQvgBqi/KmQf6MNC4Blyvr162/mnWN6rwIAG+mlKC/Kn2arfJd8BwRfrgAgRQq1IUVmn/xzvO+g1P38P7lRo0Zz9u/fv1nPmjdv/knM/kg+4+gimnvz89tV6g4qFsBG8inIK4dv165d27x9Psp/A9IGYdpf9iOxurpaQFjEszM8z3dQTocKAFKgVBsSaP3Xkn+Wx5yr5VcHKd/Nx3td+L6aTzP3N0AxqgIAG+mnIG+PHj3mM6y7zAOASSj/GyakYQnuQenjPQB4vAIAE8mlKA8tWeY+a8oBQ481a9asNyGxe/fu1XQdsgJu2l4BgInkUpQHJR5GiY1dkg4cONBs8+bNh0xIdCaM1GVkEr7D4QoATCSXojwVAKRIGaUgBQC8jgX4iKfunmvXrl1nQksvEq1+VaULMJEWebp169aucePG1yG0C+lrz+anUzTe5vtWnKkXNOam/11uWFwi2fABfktBl3scuXsYz080KRzw3Ad4vubJO6/SBfhIrl+/fi337dv3Ux6NQWCNwoQLIJYBhJsAwl9NlJBvHjz5awDfbE8/foD6e1H/n8PKRvnnwItaf1NPvhEVAORITa0eQT1LK+9koawaZ2ZtocU7sbI6jtyrvNzWU8CbfB9CV7DJr1BH+U/z7HQPcN44dOhQxwoAPBKji/zYkSNHfg8APmqrHXnUvHclSlhg+65tfuYChgPQR3PeO8hvU44ePTqndevWGWtQU1PTBX5GQtdNOS2/AXmvwGpU5gFcIfbu3bv94cOHl8VRvqdVFQ0EtOrJ0DrOFjxO/vsBasYXqFgAhJCE8ksAgoaA4IEYIJDyNRtYWQ6W0qR8zObv+XpmzNZ0wmsl6A4meft3Pz60YISzOEFm3/u8XlsAOXwIZVmSyi+BJWjQsWPHZq1atRpG3e6WsIyDiHXYyR9N/c5nxnCe34xhvQUA5vNMBPQHE+XTeo5oqIen/0ucp+5YjHk5kzG+xqOYliCu9aqXAHDG+atQ4sejBOco/2pM5zw3rzNakMPonZErSxDUSwCYetB+yq9rIKh3AFC/jxnfYjDDJ7Nfq+XnNnFbS0B5w7AkT0RZnWI+r3cAYCr1dvry74cJOazl1zUQ1DsAMIu2HAtwXhAAbJQftztIkyWodwBgNe1dFHdqEAAAxw2Y6Rm2Zrhcu4P6CADNgIXx3ZSZssO2AFD+cgRBvQMAI4B9OIAnhViAPlgA76YJKyyUAgTa9k3XdQe+zQARixVbwvdvRe0UzuS14q4OZKYL0EpZ5xAf4A02gfRfvXr11rjsUkcHFKJVRaN5gnx8Akf5L6L0ll56qX83v53LZpH/DuOjPgJgCgLR8mhgQnivA4IB5QACnNpnUPRgP2b4/Sms2aUVAHgkgMDORzB/jGrdJQKB1uifjKLN+5wubX/usS/3OTzsoxt4XwUAORLAbL5IH9k3StDlAIIwAMBfDQ5tiwoAkMCwYcMabdu2bSgLOWNpMYP4qWEUAPQ87SDAoi3Eog0N4OUJAJA9ReTbTZgIoZzz4JV/BCXeAA+j+WT3xNnwlGYQYAE+AS8rAHWrHJ52AQyNaEI3q9ZJJzBua49yDHn+afrU7Tbg8eaNMTow8gmwAmcDgJ9i3S7g73HqXIzyb41SvmirUwDwtPbr4c17FDquztQFHGWY9gw+w4OYUx2xzmylipsEAt5dZkKf9hNQtxEI4tJT9gBQa3/11VeHIICxKGlQ1CqfhaDepLzpTZo0mbFy5Uptu04spQkEZQuAPn36nIHJuwElqW9PrLUDoEVq7R06dFj02GOPHU1M6zkFpQUEZQUAp7UPpn8bi3kcnGRrp8wZ+jD5o+PXRUk2IICgQ9Cn/QRW8wRRjJQFANTa2bM/Wq3dZHo1imnn+TEnbIpa+zOFbO1h9JQaBGkGQEO82yEofAymXn9Dz+gZKl3ZdvCZQXnTi9na0wqC1AHgnHPOOZ15+NEauyfd2ilvWvv27Z8uVWtPIwjSAgAFPRyMSR7DZ2jSrV0tniHc6xZWoiRZS9EdlBQAntauvt36QGaAljAex55l/KzWvjCNrT0MXXR7HXH2dFLJZGSTt2NYCgA0ZDFmkFo7iro4wda+k/IyfXs5tPYkQYAsr2Dd/6k4ZqtoAGDOui3K0Zhdn6TO4cmTf45yHyzH1p4wCAYCghdsQVBoABSktdPSFQZ9Bn+n5zM3byusYue37A50DvATWL9dNnQWBAA4M22clq5VuMRaO33j7zRL17Jly4XEvj9iw2i55rUBAfL5ERNF37HhNUkAqLVfRKuUJ6++PRvLzoaggLxvw9y3mZdfsGLFCm3rrlfJFATI/l3kfprNrua8AeBp7erb2xVBMzsA2GYAoXXuV3TMi79b33vvvde2bNlysAj1l6QKUxAAAG1o1alnoxQXAJql+yzClyd/ScKt3Yhwn0zHoeXvgEMbOl/jrz7a2buFIeErCEUrelorL9vkgOBFGPhQEBPwPAFn8F5TJq0AoNaO0q+nEvXtSbV2KUV9+zSmfFeiLMXkG4oyP+uzy8WUL798iuSlcOqbKH8D5a8hStZa0zCr+VSc8662osXeUwAIfgj9gf08fP0Ex/jfTek1AUCV09q1ApdYa1drRdkzNW5ftWrVNh+CFQOnC8/7wXBf8ndDgZ34v4kpcwb5DgK61ViMJeR9nqHkS4WeOKIRaZJqXADPkSSji/uRh6588U3I6D+xAN+NLMjJEAgAYud8AOGMIZ/upGlvWmBEPug7/rzm5Pn7pI2zonI7d+7ctFmzZh9HAJ34nEUZ/8rPH3PoU1gUo42eITS+zbMnoe9Ruoyl+bRUvzrcLenaY4hD298WBDjZF8KzJnyyMf996hmHXHWXkFHyA4Dm5cdD5PeTMsGU9Q/KmgnyH7Jl2oiL/wfHR6mjHfW1c4DREYFpalVACd0enVsPZWhfwCzonoJA/2ZKR1g+FPgw9Ix08myH1gGm8pDyaZBPQE/gsTanXOPYwcpfCwAKnXLw4MG52lqVAMNyyhbD5INxWnsC9XuLqKI7ETg6Q0tXANGLv33IELlL2NmX9xuZVoDwl7h09e3b9/0EatqBAr1392xHqf03bNjwWgRwTJW/DRq159DY2c0CgFZ/MoJZDKORBybCiFVr5/kv6FcfyudoVVxB27ynTaQoYCBKuYi/F/L3/SHvy3F7hHzfjVKYXxmY//HI9x6fZ6EgsGj5KvorAGCyjQy8APgVL46wedmTV337EhjUVWYLbPv2mHUm+pqz3WwgPHwRXi7nb63Dlm5lAPwAzyZp1g0+95kSQQPTTV7aw++XfEFgo3zoWkeI2D62M6QZAECcTo/MN2XGk+8ttXY+DyEMBTCuE8mxhqMQ6gQ5nH5MYQm20qXcAN9aug1NlPcpMkQt1NQCgY3yKfstaDnX1J/wEisAqH98GfMXGTLNefE4QlmqOflCtHYY747gx1LHv1G+u47wGt+X8vtUxrh/ihJ4gs81BL4YXm9HPj18ypUsJjML+fWwWUjKUHzBUVF0aWisxkRdp/BXI7Awb98tTiOXC4IihUfVWeUMLX4XlZHnbyOITGtnnKnp10QTTtJJTMzcT6GaUg5K6mqmERVzvN9FyIkSVLswyWmUHEF+PmGjBr/r0qYr/eTSpUuXU/GHduY4f0mRmpfyRYRaf2TUadB7Jyj/XqHm2h3lPwc955tIBoH/ARAMKjIIGjh0KsLYN/nkzjloGVbh4ms1Jsz/LfxuPDVrwr+TJ2/lZwCAeVqHgruHNLmHQfY1FoRZZ0VI0yNavl+ZUxF23HDp1jR6X2D0cB7meja/dfT+zm9HkeUtyOvn7u9REUliEpKI8l0AKJSIr8ebyVBV1SXqOpKYTGReU59Pi8699Eirfd9itizjYDE3cQH/38FX3dvjJs0zdI/jEzi3bgynXje4snv1ujaarKGuBS1atJgbZmG6du36PuiTonWTZ63kTsfCWz++/1c+8vF5NzHlZ/QLQsOiZh2nlWk/vvHEgi2zWKCpCHys573N9JnncR5vt7cs6GyNwl/KcVYnQ99XbOrUxcuUM0nr5hHv7UR5E3XBclg+yptIeXfk7m3kt5/B16kmzp8F/Rp1DYzr8PnVIx8gMMSIXoCxNkzoyDstSEKA/0PBmqrNJK0EYnGe8auMFnUpSsmGWkXIf8ECeK1CGI2a4tYcudY2jBN1TKEOLb4EruAB4kHQrStcWhsX/H8Z1bBMFuQayNHUSeGkJ9dkAV6BiFp9WQ4T3wZxukGrIIn6tYkje5NV06ZNT2bXT/Z2S2+ljtnd6/ntILTVuhY9iEjq0SSVlfLdshwQfDlMALqYieeLaTAfNBUUoBngTLvLAmro55e2k+8uuqSptpM8JnTICXyECq4KyqyZL0zyIJtdJiYVu3kQ3CHvEm8YAFgNbNG8efM9nvIPAYDIsbLMPu/M8dIFX7J8P+czhyviMteuU7auWR/JZ1zusI3frjLoDnRDt5aWAzdsuDRQ3mrK663/deED+xw/RZ1yxv+Fj5zJN/msRO5r+L9gXbAAMJKKHg5TGsJScMWLTWa9bJSvvLldAIK5BMH4Xr+WO2NJ3r+SN3QCSw7frl27tnn7fC3HwvOgoBh6ir1H2QoG4R3z76CcDlFDYUYInbmpawn1SZFh6UbkqdFPSZO6gJOhQNulAuPnikK1GP5cQn8ohCeWfJxABTbsm7u9mTDvp9AHruTZWZ7KI51A+JOXPst9R3yg/J5RARR5T61Z161kLQygGMV7WjMJTQBoJnm/FJSJZ3sASZuNGzfWRJVV6OfuWoC2EP0oqjIJDyV8Dift+ai8ps+dYeBa8medITl31HMrM4NLmHOvwjQP5Ln8EK/yNSvYDYVsDKsLgM1H4d5IWXcBLk3kRCZou4c6dMNWJvH9ceq7IuxFjrK3Qrnaox8Yn0/T6JQTGqwykriEMmSErp02CFlo7xpVrrMadhkMaOYukRTTQYts/SKOsrWxI2vK1c/Sr24wIRz/pJr8koubtgOedmHvUp8mp0KXZAFkDxqRpo9LnrKtTjtOQabG2R8woEq3VF4OE+on807qp/fu3fsc9X/apDBAuGzPnj2DovpjlZX0det0gd67d08gFwBIsd2C+EBuiG1NLxM+i5Gn1hhU5hiTq6FM2MYIly4N375Ai9CdtHknzbMTBeReQKChWtDYWN7wFJyxiSbKLzYAkF9v6JefEph4Pgbr+VDeAkuogBMEjRfbjT5MIDCxBIdgKPbJVD8enPrHaDmYT2YzKnVs47tCoKvvDO3zc8vEArwOL9mo3TbmF1p6YW28oeNDu4CoNQ05f0xrt2UruncuIyFVxivGt6XRHXSFWA1lTCY1dEb9yrRdhuSKA6X8lu+Xe8RzN1br6ybiAjz3IYPMHbtOmse7uqDxhGTi/CGnacjJO+1tQkZB8wROQzpjYW2NjpzU0MZJTSbROiXsVCX4uAYwa+Uuk5yJrWocQW3RCkzOletq/d4+fwQA+LXfSybOH3RUIyONeFKTQuehNamBwASCD0dRTL7Ia9aiyijEc2flT9vVMtepOiDQPbpDglY5HeXLt8nuGoa/NxiWdgw6SRTl/FEW2FlbXQge8ykzciFCcWhB7lKD1TO1riNYghGgfG4+RCX9LjwMdxZrvEUfhC8N1+awuSRjDWpqarrg/4yEV43Ra3n7vK+QrbUuXnYL8/EVTmCBusYiF61HpCpFAkDUYkY76YZtrQxGUa9NEbSuUQjrkai8xXxOC9XafeiCThA9Wtpl+KedPb4Ji6F9fDovGZT2ciagTZqcP5dQIwAoM0fFznKuWc+a0hCBaTHjWhBfawGmmAr3qUvLwdpzaAUCR/maDfRdkNFhGpSrk0NhN3No17Q2eaYuGQNAlJueUXe4PAYIrsMShC40FVsigEBe/N18QqNwqc/Hkk0IMvsu3ZSn7kL3EAUmyuqFBdGqXuqSFQBEPQwb34hFdgVxGo0lmJUmzrX8Sr+vOX0dAKlGQRmrhhnXHL6mfufTqueZHB2P2lNJ2etQfs808e+lxRoAepnuoL3THZjE/5EluJGWNDOtQohLl4nzB+83wbvOUKQyxQKAONEt3JhIbdpsZ8CZ+s8xaVj/NqDVOIuJ88ciW9vly5d7N7EYl1+MjLEBIOIQwJmYTYHAJH6ATtGMS3NrsBG44/ypywg8do75Vxi7WNvQbGjJJ29eAFDFOmHL2FlDRB1LjkqyBDfbnmCNKrQUz02cP2TSmxlH73JyKUgNrTNvAKh0xfMXCPgatrk0SwiW4KtYggeSkkY+d+fGpSHK+cP5XY/z63eeMG6VBXkvEQA43YFCwQoE3l07YUSPxxLcly9X+d6dG6d+n40ifsVYhWqJQ0cS7yQGABGDWWyjtYOcwxuBdGIJJmIJ/IImGPNGS8zr7lzjijwZDZy/Gpy/Nml2/lx2EgWACsUnOM1ZQDI9sPFNLMFdcRThWJ687s61rdfE+aNM3U8QNjVsW23B8icOAFHKAY4Pc25Oq4iB17TncBT78Em+d+faSpYuR9fThUbhwrLpxk7vRhLbaoqWvyAAcFrmhxDEUj6fNOTmNlrNjw3zZrPle3dujPpCT1NT3gb4CDxtbVtfofMXDACOT6AdRTpHELnb2GH0ewjvhzZM53t3rmVdubuE/V63DtRkQ0PSeQsKABHrBJxczNfAnbJepjCvtzN8+g8bRvO5O9emHoPt6zUco2ube7LZpo5i5y04AMSQEyNPEUJNx8U/wBIoEkdqkonzB3hnAt6wEDep4cclpCgAUGWKlUOYVwWFNtoWRT6rmLeFlqyJ8wcN5wLc0G3hhabTtvyiAUCE6XwfTqHu+MmcijVIP0agtxnkK3gWfI21ERbsT9Bq1M0VnFiLCooKANGlSB8sJT/HSqJCtUYmLMEdmNVbIzMWMAM+Rk+d6AmrAjpv9sYGKiA5iRZddACIeu2hBwTPIjSjsLRMLE1iVe0biXJuUViU8+ccn2+be6LZooqSZS0JAMStnCoCMyzCrPYz4Z4WeC+TKxNM8iaZxwlKoT1/gcu+0PYLaLs+yXqLVVbJACAGHeEqHpBRfMCo3bmFEBrmX8fUQnf0yJJh/l8qRP2FLrOkABBzivvD2PlphPwZE2YR9gMI+6smeZPIY+D8bcT0Kz5QWaaSA0BSU5QSFLsQEAwwkaITtEnh4QoWO0d0mDh/Se9tMOE/yTypAIAYco6HPwUQLjBh0DloqS3ZBQMBY39ddhG4n98JNNWmHJ0/V8apAYALArZj61qUC01A4Oy5k4ISB4GJ80e9s1D+l0xoTWueVAFAQnIOcy7g60UmQnM8cK29x76Kza8eE+cPAJ7H8HSFCZ1pzZM6AEhQzsENBXcabCi42bREDcMSAwF+iSZ+Ag90oPxNKN90ldOQjeJnSyUAPCB4HBAMNRELfbWiml+XBAhMnD/q+Rqg01nDsk6pBYCk6twT+BgguNREyrTKX2M9rsn38kcT5w/AteXyqPdM6EpznlQDQILDFDdB2HMBgTfWX6BMyftohw4dRsYFgZw/Vi13Ul9gCH0q/yWt/4Qw8WlWdBBtqQeACwIFeEC5nzcU8lxi746IE1zZxPnT9DXnPXSJc9mnsgCApMzooDGxARWfxzdIk48m5gGCq21BEOX8AcI/42sojGydSGUDABcEBJT8FUoYbih9XYU3HHN92CQ/yteOpaggTrdQ3s9MyiuHPGUFAAlUFzxu3bpVQSeuNhTwE0wuXWly1t/E+eMI3OmbNm36p2Hdqc9WdgDwgGA2341uOsV/eGr//v1XhIHAxPlzhpoFvUCr2IgpSwA4QlLMH91jaKQQlPf07t27vxAUYtZwz9/5mP+kL4Eqts5r1VfOABAjDVHcdJRrNB9PvkWEhvl87m1gLPkqRIz2/IVdJPUyyjc96VRSpdpUXu4AEK+69ELBl422Yzt7+27jDp4X3nnnnZM4wjaE337C+6FBo3ieyGlmG+UUI29dAEAGBFiCqWFLt/kIU3v+cP7OqEvOnyuPugIA1xIo8mchbuK4D/OfvTkkHzCl7d26BAAXBIo8YhUMMkIpb3GT2dlcZfdu2pSXBD11DQAZmeATaKIm732DCnuLYziE1m9yu3oS+ih6GXUSAJIic/p349zF3kbuKH80ytd8Q51NdRYAjiXQZQ938gm95ydXuyj/HVr+tSg/ketw0oyeOg0ACd6JH3CnTHmUInTxBXlmc2rpO9zpp4ua63yq8wBwNejEEBiOcnX+oBOfDwIKXUH/d7qKTfy/mPOKjxbyouw0oul/AWddtKbhiDSoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
    },{
      "FullName": "Lucy Ann Johnson",
      "WentMissing": "1961",
      "Age:": "20",
      "Description": "Short brunette, was last seen wearing a green dress.",
      "Image": "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"
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="data in myArray">
      <p>Name: {{ data.FullName }}</p>
      <p>Went missing: {{ data.WentMissing }}</p>
      <p>Age: {{ data.Age }}</p>
      <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{data.Image}}" />
      <p>Description: {{ data.Description }}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could include the whole index if that helps, but tbh i don't think that's what causing the issue :( but design-wise, is ng-repeat a bad solution? because for a database manual entry seems like a stretch.

Comment: If its to much try create a fiddle or plnkr to make it reproduceable. `ng-repeat` should work for you. If you have to display a lot of data use paginations.